# Why the reusable props is not working and show undefined

Tags: css, reactjs, react-redux, react-props, mapstatetoprops

I had to use the boolean hook expression i.e isMainPage. The logic is if `isMainPage` is `true` then the `className` is `mainPageActive` if not then it should be `mainPage`, But the main problem is the props that I had put in the main component are showing me undefined. Please tell me if I m doing it wrong.

```
const WebHeader = () => {
     
  const [threeDots, setThreeDots] = useState(false);
    
  console.log(threeDots);
    
  return (
        <>
          <Sidebar isSideBarShown={threeDots} />
          <div className="threeLine">
            <button
              class="menu"
              aria-label="Main Menu"
              onClick={() => setThreeDots(!threeDots)}
            >
              <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <path
                  className={threeDots ? "openedline1 line" : "line line1"}
                  d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058"
                />
                <path
                  className={threeDots ? "openedline2 line" : "line line2"}
                  d="M 20,50 H 80"
                />
                <path
                  className={threeDots ? "openedline3 line " : "line line3"}
                  d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942"
                />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
         
      <Main isMainShown={threeDots} />
    </>
  );
};
    
export default WebHeader;
```

Here is the Main Component

```
const Main = (props, { isMainShown }) => {
  console.log(isMainShown);
  useEffect(() => {
    props.ImportForamttedFile();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div className={isMainShown ? "mainPageActive" : "mainPage"}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/GrossProfitView">
            <GrossProfitView Sheet={props.Sheet} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/data/augest-21/reports">
            <Report Sheet={props.Sheet} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Scorecard">
            <ScoreCard Sheet={props.Sheet} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Commisionview">
            <CommisionView />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Activationview">
            <ActivationView />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Accessoriesview">
            <Accessoriesview />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/TotalMobileProtection(TMP)View">
            <TotalMobileProtectionView />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Notification/AllNotifications">
            <AllNotification />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
    
const mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  return {
    Sheet: Object.values(state.Sheet),
  };
};
    
export default connect(mapStatetoProps, { ImportForamttedFile })(Main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access props this way.

```
const Main = (props) => {
 const { isMainShown } = props;
}
```

Comment: actually, props is working but isMainShown is undefined... it should be updated when i click on the button.

Comment: yeah got your problem, if you use this way you will get complete access to `props` from your props you can access `isMainShown`

Comment: Thanks, Amruth, it works. Yes, You are absolutely right.